# Dense subsets of the metric space of measurable sets with metric $d\left(A,B\right)=\mu\left(A\triangle B\right) $

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $\left(X,\mathcal{F},\mu\right)$
  be a finite measure space and define a relation on $\mathcal{F}$
  by $A\sim B\iff\mu\left(A\triangle B\right)=0$
 . It can be shown this is an equivalence relation, that $d\left(A,B\right):=\mu\left(A\triangle B\right)$
 is a metric on the quotient $\mathcal{F}^{*}:=\frac{\mathcal{F}}{\sim}$
  and that this metric space is complete.

Now let $\mathcal{A}\subseteq\mathcal{F}$
  be an algebra s.t $\mathcal{F}=\sigma\left(A\right)$
  and let $\mathcal{A}^{*}:=\frac{\mathcal{A}}{\sim}$
 , I want to show that $\mathcal{A}^{*}$
  is dense in $\left(\mathcal{F}^{*},d\right)$
 . To do that it would suffice to show that for any $F\in\mathcal{F}$
  and any $\varepsilon>0$
  there exists $A\in\mathcal{A}$
  s.t $\mu\left(A\triangle F\right)<\varepsilon$
  but I haven't been able to do that directly.

This is very reminiscent of something I saw in a proof of Caratheodory's theorem. If you consider $\mu$
  to be a measure on $\mathcal{A}$
 , disregarding $\mathcal{F}$, define an outer-measure $\mu_{0}$
  on $\mathcal{P}\left(X\right)$
  by $$\mu_{0}\left(B\right):=\inf\left\{ \sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\mathbb{\mu}\left(A_{j}\right)\ |\ B\subseteq\bigcup_{j=1}^{\infty}A_{j}\ ,A_{j}\in\mathcal{A}\ \forall j\right\}
 $$ 
 And define a set $E\in\mathcal{P}\left(X\right)$
  to be $\mu_{0}$
 -measurable if for all $\varepsilon>0$
  there exists $A\in\mathcal{A}$
  s.t $\mu_{0}\left(A\triangle E\right)<\varepsilon$
 . Then it can be shown that the collection $\mathcal{M}$
  of $\mu_{0}$
 -measurable sets is a $\sigma$
 -algebra containing $\mathcal{F}=\sigma\left(\mathcal{A}\right)$
  which proves that for any $F\in\mathcal{F}$
  and any $\varepsilon>0$
  there exists $A\in\mathcal{A}$
  s.t $\mu_{0}\left(A\triangle F\right)<\varepsilon$
 . I'm guessing one can combine this with the fact that in fact $\mu_{0}\equiv\mu$
  on $\mathcal{F}$
  (easily proven by $\pi-\lambda$
  theorem) and get the required result. But this is a really convoluted way of proving something I feel should be fairly simple....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let
$$
G = \{B\ \in \mathcal{F} \mid \forall \epsilon >0\exists A \in \mathcal{A}: \mu (A \Delta B) <\epsilon\}.
$$

It is a nice exercise to show that $G$ is a $\lambda$ system. Since it contains $\mathcal{A}$, you get the claim by Dynkins $\pi$-$\lambda$ theorem.