# A $\sigma$-algebra is complete w.r.t. the metric $d_{\mu}(A, B) := \mu(A \triangle B)$

Tags: measure-theory, metric-spaces, lp-spaces, alternative-proof, complete-spaces

I'm trying to prove below statement that appears in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1606316/dense-subsets-of-the-metric-space-of-measurable-sets-with-metric-d-lefta-b-rig?rq=1).

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ be a finite measure space. We define a pseudometric $d_\mu:\mathcal A \times \mathcal A \to [0, \infty)$ by $d_{\mu}(A, B) := \mu(A \triangle B)$. Then $d_\mu$ becomes a metric when $\mathcal A$ is considered modulo the equivalence relation $\sim$ defined by
$$
A \sim B \iff \mu(A \triangle B) = 0 \quad \forall A,B \in \mathcal A.
$$

> **Theorem:** $(\mathcal A, d_\mu)$ is a complete metric space.

1. Could you have a check on my attempt?
2. Is there other approach that do not require an excursion through $L_1$ space?

---

**My attempt:** Let $L_1 :=L_1(\Omega, \mu, \mathbb R)$. Consider the map $T:\mathcal A \to L_1, A \mapsto 1_A$. It follows from $1_{A \triangle B} = |1_A-1_B|$ that $T$ is an isometry. Because $L_1$ [is complete](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4505799/the-space-l-p-l-p-omega-mu-e-is-complete-for-p-in-1-infty), it suffices to show that $T(\mathcal A)$ is closed in $L_1$.

Let $(1_{A_n}) \subset T(\mathcal A)$ and $f \in L_1$ such that $\|1_{A_n} -f\|_1 \to 0$. [There is](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4301365/convergence-in-mathcal-l-1-implies-mu-a-e-convergence-for-a-subsequence?noredirect=1&lq=1) a subsequence $\varphi$ of $\mathbb N$ such that $1_{A_{\varphi (n)}} \to f$ $\mu$-a.e. Because $\operatorname{im} (1_{A_{\varphi (n)}}) \subset \{0, 1\}$, we have $f(x) \in \{0, 1\}$ for $\mu$-a.e. $x \in \Omega$. Let $A := f^{-1} (1)$. Then $f = 1_A$ $\mu$-a.e. It follows that $\| 1_{A_{\varphi (n)}} - 1_A\|_1 \to 0$. Because convergent sequence is Cauchy, we get $\| 1_{A_{n}} - 1_A\|_1 \to 0$. This completes the proof.