# Is my generalization about the separability of a countably generated $\sigma$-algebra correct?

Tags: measure-theory, solution-verification, metric-spaces, separable-spaces

Let $(X, \mathcal A, \mu)$ be a **$\sigma$-finite** measure space. Let $\mathcal F$ be the collection of all measurable sets with finite measure. We define a pseudometric metric $d_\mu$ on $\mathcal F$ by $d_{\mu}(A, B) := \mu(A \triangle B)$. Then $d_\mu$ becomes a metric when $\mathcal F$ is considered modulo the equivalence relation $\sim$ defined by
$$
A \sim B \iff \mu(A \triangle B) = 0 \quad \forall A,B \in \mathcal F.
$$

I'm trying to generalize [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4512936/if-a-sigma-algebra-is-countably-generated-then-its-induced-metric-from-symm) result from finite measure space to $\sigma$-finite measure space, i.e.,

> **Theorem:** If the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal A$ is countably generated, then $d_\mu$ is separable.

Could you have a check on my proof?

---

**My attempt:**  By $\sigma$-finiteness assumption, there is an increasing (w.r.t. inclusion) sequence $(X_n) \subset \mathcal A$ such that $\bigcup_n X_n = X$ and $\mu(X_n) < \infty$. Let
$$
\mathcal A_n := \{X_n \cap A \mid A \in \mathcal A\} \subset \mathcal F \subset \mathcal A \quad \forall n \in \mathbb N^*.
$$

Because $\mathcal A$ is countably generated, [so](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4182181/prove-that-mathcal-c-subseteq-mathcal-py-implies-sigmaf-1-mat) is $\mathcal A_n$. Let $d_{n}$ be the restriction of $d_\mu$ to $\mathcal A_n$. By [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4512936/if-a-sigma-algebra-is-countably-generated-then-its-induced-metric-from-symm) result, $d_n$ is separable. Let $\mathcal D_n$ be a countable dense subset of $\mathcal A_n$. Let $\mathcal D := \bigcup_n \mathcal D_n$. Then $\mathcal D$ is countable. Let's prove that $\mathcal D$ is dense in $\mathcal F$.

Fix $\varepsilon>0$ and $A \in \mathcal F$. Let $A_n := X_n \cap A \in \mathcal A_n$. Then $A_n \nearrow A$. By continuity of measure from below, there is $N$ such that
$$
d_\mu(A_N, A) = \mu(A \setminus A_N) < \varepsilon.
$$

There is $D \in \mathcal D_N$ such that $d_N (D, A_N) < \varepsilon$. It follows that
$$
d_\mu( D, A) \le d_\mu (D, A_n) + d_\mu(A_N, A) = d_N (D, A_n) + d_\mu(A_N, A) < 2 \varepsilon.
$$

This completes the proof.

Comment: I did not notice that you are restricting yourself to finite measured sets $\mathcal{F}$. In that case, I do think your arguments work.  I think that you should note that this metric is not necessarily complete.

Comment: @Keen-ameteur It seems to me that $(\mathcal F, d_\mu)$ is complete. Please see my question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4507510/a-sigma-algebra-is-complete-w-r-t-the-metric-d-mua-b-mua-triang).

Comment: The metric there might be complete, but when $\mu$ is infinite and $\sigma$-finite I don't think this is the case. Should I write the counter example I have in mind there?

Comment: @Keen-ameteur I would love to see you counter-example. On the other hand, in any case, I always restrict to the collection of measurable sets with finite measure.

Comment: You can actually disregard my remark. My proposed 'counter example' was actually not a proper Cauchy sequence.