# Generalize Theorem 4.13. in Brezis's Functional Analysis

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, banach-spaces, separable-spaces, bochner-spaces

Let $(X, \mathcal A, \mu)$ be a $\sigma$-finite measure space and $(E, |\cdot|)$ a Banach space. Fix $p \in [1, \infty)$. Let $L_p := L_p (X, \mu, E)$ and $\|\cdot\|_{L_p}$ be its norm. Here we use the [Bochner integral](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4298588/dominated-convergence-theorem-for-banach-space). I'm trying to generalize **Theorem 4.13.** in Brezis's *Functional Analysis*, i.e.,

> **Theorem:** If the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal A$ is countably generated and $E$ separable, then $L_p$ is separable.

Could you have a check on my below attampt?

---

**Proof:** Let $\mathcal F$ be the collection of all measurable sets with finite measure. We define a pseudometric metric $d_\mu$ on $\mathcal F$ by $d_{\mu}(A, B) := \mu(A \triangle B)$. Then $d_\mu$ becomes a metric when $\mathcal F$ is considered modulo the equivalence relation $\sim$ defined by
$$
A \sim B \iff \mu(A \triangle B) = 0 \quad \forall A,B \in \mathcal F.
$$

Then we have

- [Lemma 1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4512968/is-my-generalization-about-the-separability-of-a-countably-generated-sigma-al?noredirect=1&lq=1) If the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal A$ is countably generated, then $d_\mu$ is separable.

Also,

- **Lemma 2:** The space $\mathcal S := \mathcal S(X, \mu, E)$ of simple functions is dense in $\big (L_p, \|\cdot\|_{L_p} \big)$ for all $p \in [1, \infty)$. [Prop 4.8 in Amann's *Analysis III*]

By **Lemma 2**, it suffices to prove that $\mathcal S$ is separable. Let $D$ be a countable dense subset of $E$. By the finite form of a function in $\mathcal S$ and the triangle inequality, it suffices to prove that $\mathcal I := \{e 1_{A} : e\in D, A \in \mathcal F\}$ is separable. Fix some $e \in D$ such that $|e|=1$. Again, it suffices to prove that $\{e 1_{A} : A \in \mathcal F\}$ is separable. Consider the map
$$
T:\mathcal F \to L_1, A \mapsto e1_A.
$$

It follows from $1_{A \triangle B} = |1_A-1_B|$ that $T$ is an isometric embedding. By **Lemma 1**,  $d_\mu$ is separable. So $T(\mathcal F)$ is also separable. This completes the proof.